# Multi Dimensional Array's format

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a multi dimensional array and a little stuck on its format:

```
activity[currentAccount] = {
        date: aDate,
        id: aID,
        ip: aIP,
        vid: aVID,
        actor: aActor,
        action: aAction,
        data: aActionData
    };
```

This is currently in my script to where it pushes all of this data to the array.

However, currentAccount could have be the same for 30 records so i would need to be able to access it like so: `activity['1234']['action'][0]` <-- this being the first set of values for account `1234` in the array.

Would I need to change how I am storing the initial data or just need to access it a specific way?

Thanks

Comment: use JSON instead of multidimesional array

Comment: This seems more like an object, where `activity['1234']` would be `activity = { 1234 : { accountObject } }` - is this right?

Comment: @sourabhkasliwal: Your suggestion makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.

Comment: I just need to be able to access data from this array in some way but currentAccount is not unique so activity['1234'] is only going to return the first instance. I need to be able to loop through all activity['1234'] and get the properties for each

Comment: Yes, if currentAccount can be repeated you should not use it as key-value directly. It should point to an array of activities for currentAccount.

Comment: @user568109 I think that is my question then. How could I re-structure the array to be able to access it like that?

Comment: @SBB: Just simply make `aAction` an array of values, then `activity['1234']['action'][0]` will work.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - Well all of the properties need to be associated with the account number, not just one. Maybe I am just over thinking it but all i need to be able to do is `activity[currentAccount][i]` so then when i access that I can do something like `activity[currentAccount][i][action]` or  `activity[currentAccount][i].action`

Comment: @SBB: Oh ok.  I understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `activity[currentAccount]` to an array of objects.

Something like this:

```
activity[currentAccount] = [
    {
        date: aDate[0],
        id: aID[0],
        ip: aIP[0],
        vid: aVID[0],
        actor: aActor[0],
        action: aAction[0],
        data: aActionData[0]
    },
    {
        date: aDate[1],
        id: aID[1],
        ip: aIP[1],
        vid: aVID[1],
        actor: aActor[1],
        action: aAction[1],
        data: aActionData[1]
    }
];
```

Then you can access it like: `activity[currentAccount][1].action`.

Answer (score 0):

You should store it like this

```
activity[currentAccount] = [];
first = {
        date: aDate,
        id: aID,
        ip: aIP,
        vid: aVID,
        actor: aActor,
        action: aAction,
        data: aActionData
    };

activity[currentAccount][0] = first;    //either
activity[currentAccount].push(first);   //or
```

To access it use `activity['1234'][0]['action']` not `activity['1234']['action'][0]` since activity has multiple values not action.

You can use object container (`{}`) too which will allow you to use valid identifier names. But since you asked for indexes like 0,1,2,3.. . (You can't use push and length then).